# How to return back file path to updated files to ajax from controller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to return back the path of each file uploaded to ajax,since I need to display the images just uploaded at front end.

```
public ActionResult Upload()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/img"), fileName);

                file.SaveAs(path);

            }


            return Json(new { Success = true, FilePath = "ssssss" });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            //string[] lstfile = new string[];

            List<string> lstfile = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/img"), fileName);
                lstfile.Add("/Images/img/" + fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);

            }


            return Json(new { lstfile });
        }
```